# SQL QUERY Error :subquery returns more than one row

Tags: sql, database, linux

I am newbie to SQL and DATABASE learning , trying to solve the following Database problem:

We have a table with two column name and marks. Write a query based on this table which returns grades like if marks if greater than 700, it will be 'A' if it is less than 700 and greater than 500, it will be 'B' OR it will be 'C'. Main point table has only two column.

> Here's the query:

```
CREATE TABLE class (name varchar(20),marks int); 
INSERT INTO class VALUES ("anu",1000),("abhi",100),("mittal",800),("chanchal",1200),("gurpreet",750),("somesh",1000),("sonia",600),("khushbu",450),("rashi",1100),("jyoti",550); 
Select * FROM class;
```

It shows following Table:

```
| name     | marks | 

| anu      |  1000 | 

| abhi     |   100 | 

| mittal   |   800 | 

| chanchal |  1200 | 

| gurpreet |   750 | 

| somesh   |  1000 | 

| sonia    |   600 | 

| khushbu  |   450 | 

| rashi    |  1100 | 

| jyoti    |   550 |
```

---

```
SELECT * FROM class where Grade =(SELECT CASE WHEN marks >700 THEN "A" WHEN marks<700 and marks<700 THEN "B" ELSE "C" END as GRADE FROM class);
```

It shows following error:

> ERROR 1242 (21000): Subquery returns more than 1 row

Need help with the last command.

Answer (score 0):

```
select name , 
CASE WHEN marks >700 THEN 'A' WHEN marks<700 and marks<700 THEN 'B' ELSE 'C' END as GRADE
from class
```

The above query should fulfill your need , this will display the name and the grades according to the criteria set by you.
I hope by SQL you meant Sql Server.